# Adding breakpoints within Parse.com iOS saveInBackgroundWithBlock

Tags: ios, parse-platform, background-process

For example, I want to set a breakpoint within the block, but xcode just skips over it.

```
    [obj saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
           //instructions
    }];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just set the breakpoint on the line in the block. It won't trigger until the block is executed

Comment: Wow, thanks! I spent so much time trying to figure it out